# Does inclusion of an affine open into an affine scheme correspond to restriction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine scheme and $U\subset X$ be an affine open. Let $i:U\to X$ be the inclusion, and let $\phi:\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ be the induced morphism of rings.

Is $\phi$ the restriction map?

Comment: To further emphasize what Martin Brandenburg is saying let me note the following. You very casually say "let $i:U\to X$ be the inclusion". What you are thinking in your head, perhaps, is the inclusion of topological spaces, what you are actually writing is an inclusion of ringed spaces. Namely, if you can so cooly state "let $i:U\to X$ be the inclusion" as if it is an obvious thing, then you better be able to, with equal ease, tell me the induced map on global sections since this is part of the data.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks. I'll keep this in mind. I was also a bit confused by how the correspondence "ring morphisms $\leftrightarrow$ affine scheme morphisms" works. I understand now my question was obvious.

Comment: I'm glad things were cleared up! If you want clarification on the identification $\text{Mor}_{\mathbf{Ring}}(\mathcal {O}_{\text{Spec}(A)}(\text{Spec}(A)),\mathcal {O}_{\text{Spec}(B)}(\text{Spec}(B)))\cong\text{Mor}_{\mathbf{LRS}}(\text{Spec}(B),\text{Spec}(A))$, just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. But this comes from the *definition* of the *morphism* $U \to X$.

If $X$ is any ringed space and $U$ is an open subset of $X$ (i.e. the underlying topological space), then there is a morphism of ringed spaces $U \to X$ (with $\mathcal{O}_U := \mathcal{O}_X|_U$). The map on spaces is just the inclusion map. The map on sheaves is induced by the restriction maps of $\mathcal{O}_X$ (write it down!).